# Why different endpoints do not query same datasets?

Tags: sparql, endpoint

I would like to query datasets such as FOAF and DBPedia. The aim is to run quite simple requests such as “Which paintings did Magritte painted ?”,”Which are the American actor who played in American movies ?” …

So I wrote my queries, and used [DBpedia snorql](https://dbpedia.org/snorql/) to run them. Then, for some other reasons, I tried [Live DBpedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20230331070948/https://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) and [<strike>OpenLinks</strike> demo.openlinksw.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20220326003108/https://demo.openlinksw.com/sparql/) to discover that the results were different according to the endpoint.

Here are 2 examples :

1. Answer with DBpedia SnorQL but neither Live DBpedia nor <strike>OpenLinks</strike> demo.openlinksw.com

   #works of Magritte
   PREFIX dbo: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/
   PREFIX foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
   PREFIX dbp: http://dbpedia.org/property/

   SELECT * WHERE {
   ?person a dbo:Artist .
   ?person foaf:surname "Magritte"@en .
   ?work dbo:author ?person .
   OPTIONAL {?work dbp:year ?year ; dbo:museum ?museum .}
   }
   ORDER BY ?year
2. Answer with Live DBpedia but neither DBpedia SnorQL nor <strike>OpenLinks</strike> demo.openlinksw.com

#american actors from [Willem Robert van Hage R tutorial](http://%20%20%20%20http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/R/sparql_hollywood/sparql_hollywood.html%20tutorial)

```
SELECT ?actor ?movie ?director ?movie_date
       WHERE {
       ?m dc:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_films> .
       ?m rdfs:label ?movie .
       FILTER(LANG(?movie) = "en")
       ?m dbp:released ?movie_date .
       FILTER(DATATYPE(?movie_date) = xsd:date)
       ?m dbp:starring ?a .
       ?a rdfs:label ?actor .
       FILTER(LANG(?actor) = "en")
       ?m dbp:director ?d .
       ?d rdfs:label ?director .
       FILTER(LANG(?director) = "en")
       }
       LIMIT 1000
```

I thought an endpoint was simply a tool to query dataset whatever it is. So I thought that you can query DBPedia and FOAF from dbpedia, live dbpedia or <strike>openlinks</strike> demo.openlinksw.com ..

I read that actually different endpoints use different datasets but I can’t get why, as you give specific URI to reach.

Why do same query returns different results according to the SPARQL endpoint ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't get the question...or better said, I don't understand why you don't understand that 1) a SPARQL endpoint just provides access to the data that is loaded and that 2) different public endpoints might indeed contain different data.

Comment: DBpedia is based on extracting data from of Wikipedia, and indeed, Wikipedia data changes over time - people call it dynamic data. Now, the question is how to keep the RDF data up to date? Most obvious way, load dumps periodically, indeed this is time consuming and can't be done every second. Thus, data is out of sync. The other option is to just apply the changeset, i.e. the diff. This is only done by DBpedia Live (with some delay indeed). The other two services you mentioned just loaded some dump (last is 2016-10 release late 2017). For sure, this data is much older than the live dataset.

Comment: Moreover, if you go to the DBpedia dataset page, you can see that there are a lot of additional data - which is more or less optional. Not each public service has everything loaded, thus, here is another source of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like different instances of SQL DBMS (such as [in no particular order and without implication of endorsement] OpenLink Virtuoso, Oracle, MySQL, Informix, SQL Server, Sybase, DB2, PostgreSQL, Ingres, Progress OpenEdge, and many others) hold different data, different instances (read: SPARQL endpoints) of RDF RDBMS, also known as Quadstores or Triplestores (such as [in no particular order and without implication of endorsement] OpenLink Virtuoso, AllegroGraph, Stardog, Neo4J, MarkLogic, and many others) hold different data.

You cannot query Joe's database in DBMS A through Fred's database in DBMS B -- unless someone has already told Fred's database and/or DBMS about Joe's database and/or DBMS (e.g., VDBMS functionality), or you include some information about Joe's database and/or DBMS in your query (e.g., SPARQL Federation), etc.

(A "DBMS" is a Database Management System, such as listed above.  A "database" is a collection of data, typically stored in a [large] document, which is managed by a DBMS.)

Of particular note relative to your question --

- [FOAF](http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/) is an ontology, a vocabulary, which is used to describe entities.
- [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/resource/DBpedia) is a dataset (which has had various versions over time), and a project, and an organization, and various other things (the ambiguity of literal identifiers!).
- [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) (not "openlinks") is a company which produces [OpenLink Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), among other data-related software and services, and which provides a number of live endpoints on the web -- including [the main DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). *(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) is also my employer.)*

Comment: In addition, the second query doesn't work because people for whatever reason tend to omit namespace declarations. `dc:` is reserved for  `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/` but the correct namespace for `subject` would be `http://purl.org/dc/terms/` which in fact is prefixed by `dct:`. The same for the properties, it should be `dbo:starring` and `dbo:director`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's much clearer now ! Both TallTed and AKSW comments allowed me to understand what is really an endpoint and what is the difference with the RDBMS itself. Thanks also for the other details :)

Comment: One more general question : I don't get how to know which namespace is the correct one. for example "released" is dbp but "starring" and "director" are dbo (thus dbp works well too). Each time I'm checking on the namespace, but it is quite long. Is there a rule to know which one to use or is it from experience ?

Comment: @J.Delannoy I think your latter comments are what we call "new questions" and should be raised as such.